# Delegate method called when silent push notification/push notification hits device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement push notification on ios8. which delegate method is going to hit, when app is in background and push notification hits device? Whether any delegate message will hit when push notification reaches device and application is in background? Can i read push notification message inside my app?

Comment: in didreceiveremotenotification you can log the push notification message.

Comment: @sanjeet when app is in foreground or background?

Comment: in both the conditions

Answer (score 0):

Delegate method which tells the app that a push notification arrived and that indicates there is data to be fetched: `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

Yes, you can read push notifications message inside app, this data is in userinfo NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *aps = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", alert);
} else if ([alert isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [alert objectForKey:@"body"]);
}
```

More info in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:).

Comment: I am using same delegate method. But it is hitting only when battery is plugged in and app is in background. When i unplug battery, the above delegate method is not hitting.In some cases i receiving but in some cases i am not receiving.

Comment: @user2533604 If you are sending multiple notifications to the same device or computer within a short period of time, the push service will send only the last one. Check here for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html - "Some Notifications Received, but Not All"